# Algorithm to generate an undirected graph with path to all nodes with a maximum degree?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I'm trying to generate an undirected graph in which each node has a maximum degree associated with it. That is, if a node has a maximum degree of 2, it can connect to at most two nodes (connected node would be allowed, but not 0). My problem is that I'm trying to generate a graph in which its possible to get from one node to the other. Currently, I can have nodes "randomly" connect to one other, but the problem is that its possible to create divided graphs, ie if you have 10 nodes, then sometimes inadvertently two graphs of 5 nodes each forms. If anyone knows of an efficient solution, I'd love to hear it!

EDIT: Suppose that I have a graph with ten nodes, and I specify a maximum degree of 2. In this case, here is something that would be desirable:

[image: Desirable Graph]

Whereas this is what I'm trying to avoid:

[image: Undesirable Graph]

Both graphs have a maximum degree of 2 per node, but in the second image, it's not possible to select an arbitrary node and be able to get to any other arbitrary node.

Comment: This is one of those cases where a picture really would be worth a thousand words.

Comment: this problem is a well-known graphing problem, the name of which currently escapes me. there's a polynomial-time algorithm for it though. Although i might misunderstand your requirements, since that algorithm handles the maximum case, and might fail on cases where maximum is impossible.

Comment: Why you cannot just connect all nodes to create a line?

Comment: I'm assuming he needs to maximize density

Comment: here's a nice source: http://gilleain.blogspot.ca/2012/07/kiralys-method-for-generating-all.html

Comment: That's a doable solution Piotr- I was trying to avoid that. Perhaps I'll randomly sort the nodes, connect them linearly, and then choose random nodes until the maximum degree of each node is satisfied.

Comment: @the_man_slim are you looking for a solution in the case where nodes have different maximum degrees? and are you trying to maximize density?

Comment: @the_man_slim could you create a random tree over n nodes and then keep adding edges that dont make the maximum degree exceed the limit you want? A graph is connected iff it has a spanning tree, so you could just start out with some random spanning tree.

Comment: @ Filipq I was trying for a solution in which each node has the same maximum degree. Ideally, I'd maximize density.

Comment: @ G Bach that's also a doable solution!

Comment: @the_man_slim This would allow you both random graphs and optimizing for some predicate pertaining to the density of the graph; for example, if you want a maximum degree of k, you could start out with a spanning tree that has inner node degrees in [k/2; 3/4*k] to add a bit of randomization, and an according number of leaves. To optimize for density, you could use some random distribution that will iteratively add new edges to the graph without violating the degree maximum while preferring nodes of higher degree.

Comment: On the other hand, there is a group of graphs that maximize density while keeping a limit on the degree (call that limit DELTA), which would be the class of connected DELTA-regular graphs; that's the class of connected graphs for which every vertex has degree exactly DELTA. k-regular graphs are not unique for a given number of vertices in general; maybe the case is different if we add the requirement of connectivity, but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: If a connected k-regular graph is what you are actually after, maybe [this paper](http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/pdf/pub/FastGenRegGraphJGT.pdf) will be of use to you; [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph#Generation) said it describes an algorithm that generates regular graphs.

Comment: Could you show an example for k=3, with say 5-6 nodes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem is a pretty well-known problem in graph theory, soluble in polynomial time, the name of which I forget (which is probably "find a graph given its degree sequence"). Anyhow, Király's solution is a nice way to do it, explained much better [here](http://gilleain.blogspot.ca/2012/07/kiralys-method-for-generating-all.html) than by me. This algorithm solves for the exact graphs that satisfy the given degree sequence, but it should be easy to modify for your more loose constraints.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution would be to build it as an N-way tree -- if the maximum degree is two, you end up with a binary tree.

To make it undirected, you'll have pointers not only to the "child" nodes, but also a backward pointer to the "parent" node. At least presumably, that one doesn't count toward the degree of the node (if it does, your degree of two basically ends up as a doubly-linked linear list instead of a tree).

Edit: post-clarification, it appears that the latter really is the case. Although they're *drawn* different (with links going in various different directions) your first picture showing the desired result is topologically just a linear linked list. As noted above, since you want an undirected graph, it ends up as a doubly linked list.

Comment: it appears from the question that each node has its own respective maximum degree, not necessarily the same for each.

Comment: Correct- although for the simulation I'm trying to run I'm just assuming that there is a global maximum degree.

Comment: ah, that simplifies matters greatly then

Comment: Just for terminology's sake: a graph that is a cycle with exactly one edge missing usually is called a path.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you already know what the graph should look like, so I believe if you can use a depth-first search approach. Although breath-first search can be used to avoid recursion.

For example, if you have the nodes 1-5, and k=2, then you can build a graph by starting at node 1, and then simply randomly choosing an unvisited node. Like so:

```
1 [Start at 1]
1-2 [expand 2, add edge(1,2) to graph]
1-2-3 [expand 3, add edge(2,3) to graph]
1-2-3-4 [expand 4, add edge(3,4) to graph]
1-2-3-4-5 [expand 5, add edge(4,5) to graph]
1-2-3-4-5-1 [expand 1, add edge(5,1) to graph] (this step may or may not be done)
```

If an edge is never used twice, then p paths will lead to degree p*2 overall, with the degree of the start and end nodes dependent on if the paths are really a tour. To avoid duplicate work, it is probably easier to just label of the vertices as the integers 1 through N, then create edges such that each vertex, v, connects to the vertex numbered (v+j) mod (N+1) where j and (N+1) are [co-prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relatively_prime) < N-1. The last bit making things a bit problematic, as the number of co-primes from 1 to N can be limited if N is not prime. This means solutions don't exist for certain values, at least in the form of a new Hamiltonian path/tour. However, if you ignore the co-prime aspect and simply make j be integers from 1 thru p, then go through each vertex and create the edges (instead of using the path approach), you can make all the vertices have degree k, where k is an even number >= 2. This is achievable in O(N*k), although it may be pushed back as far as O(N^2) if co-prime method is used.

Thus the path for k=4 would look like this, if started at 1, with j=2:

```
1 [Start at 1]
1-3 [expand 3, add edge(1,3) to graph]
1-3-5 [expand 5, add edge(3,5) to graph]
1-3-5-2 [expand 2, add edge(5,2) to graph]
1-3-5-2-4 [expand 4, add edge(2,4) to graph]
1-3-5-2-4-1 [expand 1, add edge(4,1) to graph] (this step may or may not be done)
```

Since |V| = 5 and k = 4, the resulting edges form a complete graph, which is expected. It's also works out since 2 and 5 are co-prime.

Obtaining an odd degree is a bit more difficult. First obtain the degree k-1, then edges are added in such a way an odd degree is obtained overall. It seems fairly easy to get very close (with one or two exceptions) to all edges being an odd degree, but it seems impossible or at least very difficult with odd number of vertices, and requires a careful selection of edges with even number of vertices. The section of which, isn't easy to put into an algorithm. However, it can be approximated by simply picking two unused vertices and creating an edge between them such that the vertices are not used twice, and the edges are not used twice.